# Prevent sharing of environmental variables windows <-> wsl subsystem

Tags: python, terminal, environment-variables, esp-idf

I'm using an SDK on both windows and in wsl ubuntu. The SDK provide some functionality through a python script that collects environment information (env variables) and locates certain resources based on it. Now I'm getting this error:

```
  File "/home/myuser/dev/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py", line 1099, in get_user_defined_targets
    if env == idf_env_json['idfSelectedId']:
KeyError: 'idfSelectedId'
```

(The SDK in question is the esp-idf development framework, link to the script in question: [click](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/tools/idf_tools.py))

When I follow this error inside `idf_tools.py` I get to this line eventually:

```
idf_env_file_path = os.path.join(global_idf_tools_path, IDF_ENV_FILE)  # type: ignore
        with open(idf_env_file_path, 'r') as idf_env_file:
            return json.load(idf_env_file)
```

So it seems that the idf_env_json is loaded from a json file found in the systems `global_idf_tools_path`. Now my suspicion is that the python loader will load the windows json file because for whatever reason this variable will be dominant, and hence the variable `idf_env_json` will have the wrong entries. Is there a way I can exclude certain or maybe all variables from the wsl so that those two systems don't intermix so badly?

Comment: what is the value of `global_idf_tools_path` under WSL?  Does it contain both a widows path and a linux path and you want only the linux path.  Alternatively, do you just want to remove this env variable all together when inside your python app?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was not related to windows variables, but I didn't export a variable called `IDF_TOOLS_PATH` before sourcing `. export.sh`

---

Regarding the implied question: You can prevent the automatic appendix of Windows PATH to the linux path variable using a file called `wsl.conf` in `/etc` in the respective distro.

There's an ongoing discussion in this thread:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1890